# NHibernate - LINQ Query Many to Many Issue

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm trying to upgrade an existing application to use NHibernate. My database has the following tables:

```
Sites:
- Id (PK)
- Name

Categories:
- Id (PK)
- Name

CategoriesSite
- CategoryId (PK)
- SiteId (PK)
- Active
```

For each category and site a record may or may not exist in the CategoriesSite table. If an item exists in the CategoriesSite table then it can turn the Category off by setting Active to false. **If it doesn't then it assumes Active is true**.

I'd like to create a LINQ query in NHibernate to filter for categories of a particular site (that are active). For example say I have the following data:

```
Sites:
Id | Name
1  | Site 1
2  | Site 2

Categories:
Id | Name
1  | Category 1
2  | Category 2

CategoriesSite:
CategoryId | SiteId | Active
1          | 1      | True
1          | 2      | True
2          | 1      | False
```

I could say:

```
var categories = session.Query<CategorySite>()
                        .Where(s => s.Site.Id == 2 && s.Active)
                        .Select(s => s.Category)
                        .ToList();
```

However this will only get Category 1 and not Category 2 which I'd like it to do. I was wondering if anyone has done anything similar and could suggest either a way to query this or offer any recommendations on how I can map this scenario better.

Comment: Please profile the generate sql query and also show us your mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i've solved this. I added a one to many collection against the Category for the list of Categorory Sites. This allows me to say:

```
var categories = session.Query<Category>()
                        .Where(c => !c.Sites.Any(s => s.Site.Id == 2 && !s.Active))
                        .ToList();
```

This means it will only not return the category when it has been set in-active and will still return the Category when no record exists in the CategoriesSite table.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the generated query, I can only guess but, try this instead:

```
var categories = session.Query<CategorySite>()
                    .Where(s => s.SiteId == 2 && s.Active) // not s.Site.Id
                    .Select(s => s.Category)
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: Hi thanks but my query was just an example and was trying to show the problem. I think i've come up with a solution though.